# How to include third lib into vscode on windows in c++ lang?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, jsoncpp

I have set up my vscode env with mingw64 for c++, and now it can use internal lib and compiled succeed, but when i want to use jsoncpp third lib in my project, i got errors:

```
fatal error: json/json.h: No such file or directory
    #include <json/json.h>
```

this is what i did:

1, mingw structure:

[image]

2,vscode project structure:

[image]

3,c_cpp_properties.json

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "D:\\app\\msys64\\mingw64/**",
                "F:\\project\\cppwork\\libs\\include/json/**",
                "D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0",
                "D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32",
                "D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/backward",
                "D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include",
                "D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include",
                "D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include-fixed"
               
            ],
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceRoot}",
                    "F:\\project\\cppwork\\libs/**",
                    "D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0",
                "D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32",
                "D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/backward",
                "D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include",
                "D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include",
                "D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include-fixed"
                ]
            },
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

4,tasks.json:

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe 生成活动文件",
            "command": "D:\\app\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "-I",
                "F:\\project\\cppwork\\libs\\include/",
                "-L",
                "F:\\project\\cppwork\\libs\\jsoncpp",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "调试器生成的任务。"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

5,lanuch.json

```json
{  
    "version": "0.2.0",  
    "configurations": [  
        {  
            "name": "(gdb) Launch", // 配置名称，将会在启动配置的下拉菜单中显示  
            "type": "cppdbg",       // 配置类型，这里只能为cppdbg  
            "request": "launch",    // 请求配置类型，可以为launch（启动）或attach（附加）  
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/exe/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",// 将要进行调试的程序的路径  
            "args": [],             // 程序调试时传递给程序的命令行参数，一般设为空即可  
            "stopAtEntry": false,   // 设为true时程序将暂停在程序入口处，一般设置为false  
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}", // 调试程序时的工作目录，一般为${workspaceFolder}即代码所在目录  
            "environment": [],  
            "externalConsole": true, // 调试时是否显示控制台窗口，一般设置为true显示控制台  
            "MIMode": "gdb",  
            "miDebuggerPath": "D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/gdb.exe", // miDebugger的路径，注意这里要与MinGw的路径对应  
            "preLaunchTask": "g++", // 调试会话开始前执行的任务，一般为编译程序，c++为g++, c为gcc  
            "setupCommands": [  
                {   
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",  
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",  
                    "ignoreFailures": true  
                }  
            ]  
        }  
    ]  
}
```

6, main cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <json/json.h>

using namespace std;

void parse_json(Json::Value data){
    Json::Value::Members mem = data.getMemberNames();

    for (auto iter = mem.begin(); iter!=mem.end();iter++){
        cout << *iter << "\t: ";
        if (data[*iter].type() == Json::objectValue){
            cout <<endl;
            parse_json(data[*iter]);
        }
        else if (data[*iter].type() == Json::arrayValue){
            cout << endl;
            auto cnt = data[*iter].size();
            for (auto i=0; i<cnt;i++){
                parse_json(data[*iter][i]);
            }
        }
        else if (data[*iter].type() == Json::stringValue){
            cout << data[*iter].asString() << endl;
        }
        else if (data[*iter].type() == Json::realValue){
            cout << data[*iter].asDouble() << endl;
        }
        else if (data[*iter].type() == Json::uintValue){
            cout << data[*iter].asUInt()<<endl;
        }
        else{
            cout << data[*iter].asInt() <<endl;
        }

    }
    return;
}



int main()
{   
    std::string v1 = "{\"name\": \"jim\", \"tags\": [\"football\", \"diving\"]}";
    Json::Value value;
    Json::Reader reader;

    if (!reader.parse(v1, value)){
        return 0;
    }
    parse_json(value);
}
```

7, errors:

```
hello.cpp:4:10: fatal error: json/json.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <json/json.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

i was first time to configure vscode to c++ and reference third part lib, please help me to solve it , thans in advance :)

when i use command line to compile:

```bash
g++ .\hello.cpp -o hello  -I F:\\project\\cppwork\\libs\\include
```

another error issued:

```
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Locson::Value::getMemberNames[abi:cxx11]() const'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Locson::Value::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Locson::Value::type() const'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Locson::Value::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Locson::Value::Value(Json::Value const&)'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\LocJson::Value::~Value()'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\LocJson::Value::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\LocJson::Value::type() const'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\LocJson::Value::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\LocJson::Value::size() const'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\LocJson::Value::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\LocJson::Value::operator[](int)'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\LocJson::Value::Value(Json::Value const&)'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\LocJson::Value::~Value()'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\LocJson::Value::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\LocJson::Value::type() const'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\LocJson::Value::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\LocJson::Value::asString[abi:cxx11]() const'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\LocJson::Value::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\LocJson::Value::type() const'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\LocJson::Value::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\LocJson::Value::asDouble() const'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\LocJson::Value::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\LocJson::Value::type() const'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\LocJson::Value::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\LocD:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\cckmQ1IM.o:hello.cpp:(.text+0x51a): undefined reference to `Json::Reader::parse(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, Json::Value&, bool)'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\cckmQ1IM.o:hello.cpp:(.text+0x543): undefined reference to `Json::Value::Value(Json::Value const&)'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\cckmQ1IM.o:hello.cpp:(.text+0x561): undefined reference to `Json::Value::~Value()'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\cckmQ1IM.o:hello.cpp:(.text+0x592): undefined reference to `Json::Value::~Value()'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\cckmQ1IM.o:hello.cpp:(.text+0x5ef): undefined reference to `Json::Value::~Value()'
D:/app/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\cckmQ1IM.o:hello.cpp:(.text+0x614): undefined reference to `Json::Value::~Value()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: If you use CMake as your Makefile generator, you can tell VS Code to use its `compile_commands.json` file to automatically configure your build environment.

Comment: Exactly *where* on your disk is the `json.h` header file located?

Comment: F:\project\cppwork\libs\include\json   as show in the project structure picture, my third lib is under libs directory

Comment: @SimonC
later i will try cmake, i want it to use g++ first, thanks.

Comment: It still uses G++ in the background, but provides an easily extensible frontend for you and other developers (including yourself in 6 months time), which makes life a lot easier. If you're insistent on using G++ alone, then add `-I${workspaceFolder}/libs/include` to your tasks.json

Comment: @SimonC
thanks for your advise, in official project we used cmake for build, but this is just for test some function, just a little test code, so i decided use g++ for convinient, by the way, i tried -I${workspaceFolder}/libs/include, it stiil not worked.

Comment: for your second problem have you compiled the json lib, and have you addded it to the compile command

Answer (score 0):

The problem are these lines in `tasks.json`:

```
"-o",
"-I",
"F:\\project\\cppwork\\libs\\include/",
```

The first one, `-o`, is naming the output file. You name it `-I` and then use `F:\\project\\cppwork\\libs\\include/` as an input file which is wrong.

You have placed

```
"${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
```

in the wrong location, or added you custom  options in the wrong location.

You should have

```
"-o",
"${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
"-I",
"F:\\project\\cppwork\\libs\\include/",
```

Comment: yes, i noticed that, but exchange that two place, still not work.

Comment: @Jim If you get new problems, then please ask a new question.